# How to install git on CloudLinux server?

Tags: linux, git, server

I'm trying to install git on my CloudLinux server over ssh. 
When I type following:

`install git`

it says

`missing file operand after 'git'`

I also made a folder /home/websitename/git and typed the following code:

```
install git -d /home/websitename/git
```

When I press enter nothing happens.
Im new to the command line and linux. Hope you understand my question. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **yum** package manager to install git.

```
yum -y install git
```

Comment: Can you give the output of: `cat /etc/*-release`?

Comment: cat: /etc/*-release: No such file or directory

Comment: And the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: I hope here is no sensitive data: Linux spirit.global.ba 3.10.0-614.10.2.lve1.4.50.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon May 22 16:28:14 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: This is not sensistive data. The output of this command give system informations.
This is needed to be sure of your OS version. Based on your answer, yum is the right solution.
Apparently your yum installation is not running properly. You may want to have a look at [link](http://kbase.licensecube.com/additional-licenses/why-doesn-t-yum-work-after-installing-cloudlinux.html)

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin. When I type the code from the given link, all comands work except the last one. Is says: "-bash: Idnconfig: command not found". I will not bother you any more, I will ask for help the support from my hosting provider. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.